# iis 8 extending the file upload size

Tags: iis-8

i did like i saw in many threads, like going to `Internet Information Server Manager` then to the site then `Request Filtering` and then on the right `Edit Feature Settings...` then i set the `Maximum allowed content length` to 1000000000, and restart the web site, but it didn't work, the second method i tried is that i have added the following:

```
<system.webServer>
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1000000000" />
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

in the `Web.config` file in the web site and i restarted the web site,but still getting the error `Maximum request length exceeded.`
so is there any solution or any other step i missed ?